# TF30063 Error in Test Professional 2010 / Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I am receiving the following error when attempting to run my tests:

> You cannot run the selected tests TF30063: You are not authorized to access `http://localhost:9899/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Everything else works fine, I can create issues and bugs, I can plan tests but when I run them I always get this error.

Comment: Are you running in a different domain or workgroup or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes (from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221211756/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/lab_management/archive/2009/10/26/troubleshooting.aspx#e3_13))

- The password of the account under
  which the test controller service is
  running has expired.
- The account
  under which test controller is
  running does not have permissions on
  the team foundation server.

Resolution:

- Try to restart the test controller service. If it fails to start because of logon failure error, then password of the account has expired.

  - To fix it, do the following: -

    - Open test controller configuration tool and reconfigure the test controller using the latest password.
    - Go back to client machine on which you have opened MTM or environment viewer and repair the capability.
- ```
   Open the test configuration tool and reconfigure the test controller. This tool will grant the required permissions on the team foundation server.  (If you are not unable to do that, you can add the test controller service account to the "project collection test service accounts" group of your team project.2.
  ```